# How to write down the order of a tuple

Tags: notation

I want to write down the order of tuples $(a, b)$ with $a,b \in \{1,...,n\}$.

What is a good way to do so?

Right now I wrote: $(1,1),(1,2),\ldots,(1,n),(2,1),(2,2),\ldots,(2,n),(3,1),\ldots,(n,n)$

I'm unsure about the last part $(3,1),\ldots,(n,n)$.

Do you have any suggestions?

---

**EDIT:**

What I'm about is, how to write it down.

I definitely want to write down the order.

Less important is the question about the separator. I don't think, that `<` would be a good idea.

The more important question is, if $(3,1),\ldots,(n,n)$ makes clear, what is meant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should have a look at [Lexicographical order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order). Personally, I would not order such a set, but instead use the set notation $$A \times A := \left\{ (a,b) : a \in A, b \in A\right\}$$ where in your case $A := \{1,...,n\}$. A set without any specific structure does not have the notion of order.

To answer your question, I would write $$(1,1),...,(1,n),(2,1),...,(2,n),...,(n,1),...,(n,n)$$